# placeholder variable for js function

Tags: javascript, jquery, quill

I have instantiated four versions of quill on one page. Now I want to get the content of each. Is it possible to create a funtion that identifies which instantiated version of Quill I am referring to by sending the name.

```
$.fn.getQuillContent = function(instantiatedquill)
    {
    var content =
        {
        text: instantiatedquill.getContents(),
        };
    };
```

Comment: I think you should create something (object, function) that will contain reference each Quill version (it may also initialize it) and than return proper instance when you ask for it, depending on name.

Comment: can you add more detail, this could be the answer

Answer (score 0):

Basically, create a handler that would instantiate your Quill and store their instances for later re-use

```
class QuillHandler {
  constructor () {
    // this private var would map all different Quill instances through the page
    this._instances = {}
  },

  instanciate (id, node, options) {
    // if trying to instanciate already instanciated Quill instance, return it (or throw an Error?)
    if (this._instances[id]) {
      return this._instances[id]
    }
  }

  // would return undefined if do not exist, otherwithe Quill instance
  get (id) {
    return this._instances[id]
  }
}
```

In your file, instantiate your Quills with your fresh new handler, and retrieve each instance by the id you used to create it

```
const handler = new QuillHandler

handler.instanciate('quill1', node, {})
handler.instanciate('quill2', node, {})
handler.instanciate('quill3', node, {})
handler.instanciate('quill4', node, {})

// get quill 4 contents
handler.get('quill4').getContents()
```